# Java Applets and HTML

Tags: java, html, applet

I've got a Java applet that will only work correctly one time on any browser.  I've run through the java console and cleared the class cache, refreshed the page, reloaded the browser, emptied the browser cache and I can only get this applet to work once. I've tried chrome, IE10 and FireFox.  any help is greatly appreciated.

here is the applet code:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SolarSystemV3 extends Applet{

int input;

public void init()
{

    String webInput = getParameter("mer");
    if(webInput != null)
        input = Integer.parseInt(webInput);

}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{

    if(input == 1)
    {
        g.drawString("hello mercury", 25, 25);
    }

}


}
```

here is the HTML:

```
<body>
<article>
<img src="mercury.jpg" alt="Mercury"/>
<h1>Mercury</h1>
<applet code = "SolarSystemV3.class" width="320" height="120" 
<param = "mer" value = "1"/>
</applet>
</article>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Braj An `int` can't be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here in your HTML. `name` attribute of `param` tag is missing.

```
<param = "mer" value = "1"/>
```

use

```
<param name = "mer" value = "1"/>
```

The parameter `mer` is not properly defined in HTML.

For more info have a look at [Defining and Using Applet Parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/param.html)

Answer (score 2):

> ..here is the HTML:

No it's not.  I don't mean it is not there, I mean what's there is not HTML.  It is some rubbish hacked out by a programmer that is *pretending to be* HTML.  There are at least 3 errors in it.

To find out what the errors are, use an [HTML validation service](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: Yes I haven't noticed it. I just noticed `applet` tag. Its not a HTML.

Comment: @Braj  That's why I recommend to programmers to check their 'HTML' with a validation service.  Programmers would have to be the worst authors of HTML on the planet.  Amateurs generally use an editing app. for HTML and those apps. do a better job, but programmers think to themselves "HTML is just mark-up, I can write it off the top of my head".  Unfortunately, they are wrong about that.